# How to get Gallio and NCover 1.5.8.2 to work on the command line?

Tags: gallio

I have seen some examples that use gallio such as this:

```
Gallio.Echo.exe Widget.Tests.dll /runner:NCover /runner-property:NCoverCoverageFile='C:\Temp\WidgetCoverage.xml' /runner-property:NCoverArguments='//eas .*.Tests;Gallio;MbUnit;OtherIgnoredAssembly'
```

When I run this, it gives me an error stating that the '//eas .*.Tests;Gallio;MbUnit;OtherIgnoredAssembly' can not be found?
I am looking for an example on how have the correct NCoverAgurments for 1.5.8? I need to register the CoverLib.lib COM object as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NCover v1.58 does not support the //eas argument.  Use the //a argument and specify the list of assembly names that you want to profile.  Be sure to only specify the assembly display name, not its path or filename.